# why displays only 2 nodes instead of 3 nodes in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, installation, cluster-computing

I have first developed 2 node cluster in hadoop. which had setup successfully.
After that I have added one more node.
But username of third node is different.
so, I have add config file in ssh. to set username and ip address.
Now, I have started all 3 nodes. It starts datanode and node manager in 3rd node on jps command.
But, in gui it displays only 2 nodes.
I can't understand what is the reason behind it, please, can any one tell the solution?

Comment: Look into the 3rd node datanode/nodemanager logs and on the namenode/resourcemanager logs.

Comment: in node manager                                                 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From AHDCPU00810/192.168.33.123 to 0.0.0.0:8031 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Comment: in resource manager  ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

Comment: do a diff of yarn-site.xml on nodes 1 (or 2) vs. node 3. Specially `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` value. Which Hadoop version is this?

Comment: 2.4.1 hadoop version

Comment: there is no configuration added in yarn-site.xml

Comment: is there any need to configure yarn-site.xml?

Comment: Yup. Seems like you left `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` as `0.0.0.0`. Look at any working node `yarn-site.xml`. Ditto for hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml etc.

Comment: there is nothing in yarn-site.xml in working node.

Comment: How did you set it up? did you modify directly `yarn-defaults.xml` by any chance? A node cannot come up and be functional w/o proper config values, so the config must come from *somewhere*.

Comment: I have setup core-site.xml, mapreduce-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml but not any yarn files